# Bad Request Error message express and passport

Tags: javascript, express, passport.js

I have a very simple express API that auth with passport.js :

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
const passport = require("passport");

passport.use(
  new LocalStrategy(function (username, password, done) {
    if (username === "admin" || password === "password") {
      // Authentication succeeded
      return done(null, { id: 1, username: "admin" });
    } else {
      return done(null, false);
    }
  })
);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("ok");
});
app.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local"), function (req, res) {
  res.json({ message: "Authentication successful" });
});
app.listen(3000, () => {
console.log(`http://localhost:3000/`);
});
```

When I request to '/login' EX:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/login
    Content-Type: application/json

    {
        "username":"admin"
        ,"password":"password"
    }
```

The Response said **Bad Request**

I'm new to Express.js and It's hard to find the resources to learn ... I hope you'll help me

Comment: if (username === "admin" && password === "password") - use **&&** (and) not **||** (or).

Comment: What mater .... That not the point of the error 

Answer (score -1):

you messed up your route `/login` just a little bit:

```
//app.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local"), function (req, res) {
//  res.json({ message: "Authentication successful" });
//});

app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
    passport.authenticate("local", (err, user, info) => {
      // if (err) {
      //   return res.status(500).json({ message: "Authentication error" });
      // }
      // if (!user) {
      //   return res.status(401).json({ message: "Authentication failed" });
      // }
      res.json({ message: "Authentication successful" });
    })(req, res);
});
```